# Syntax for query that has a link in it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to figure out the correct syntax for this query

```
CASE WHEN SH10.SHIP_VIA_CODE1 IN ('01','02','03','05','42','44','46')
THEN '<a href="http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track=yes&trackNums='
     + RTRIM(LTRIM(CRC_VW_SH10_B.WAYBILL_NUMB))
     + '">CRC_VW_SH10_B.WAYBILL_NUMB</a>'
ELSE CRC_VW_SH10_B.WAYBILL_NUMB 
END  AS [{TrackingNumb}]
```

I require the CRC_VW_SH10_B.WAYBILL_NUMB inside the link to not be part of the string but I keep getting errors when trying to place my single quotation marks before the closing  tag.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: MicroSoft SQL 08 R2

Comment: 1) You need to give us the entire query.  2) You need to give us the exact error message you're receiving.  I tested an analog of this query out locally, and it's fine.  The error is not in the part you've quoted here. Your question doesn't have the necessary information needed to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure, that your column `WAYBILL_NUMB` is not a string type but rather some number type. You must cast this in order to use `+`concatenation.

Further more it is in general not a good idea to create XML or (X)HTMML on string base due to character escaping. It is much better to use `FOR XML` for this:

```
THEN
(
    SELECT 'http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track=yes&trackNums=' + RTRIM(LTRIM(CAST(CRC_VW_SH10_B.WAYBILL_NUMB AS VARCHAR(100)))) AS [a/@href]
          ,'CRC_VW_SH10_B.WAYBILL_NUMB' AS a FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE 
)
```

Comment: Make sure the ELSE uses a similar subquery that builds the markup around the waybill num. Otherwise the THEN ends up looking like link, and the ELSE looks like just a string of numbers.

Comment: actually that is what we want since at the moment we do not bring back their shipping numbers in the required format yet. So the UPS orders will have a tracking link while some of the other freight deliveries will not have one yet.

Comment: and I was able to figure out by looking at concat some I realized that I needed to also combine the field name like this + CRC_VW_SH10_B + and moving some of my single quotes around